# I want to be able to find a single word in my database using .find()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my schema for making a reservation. When I make a reservation I am able to make a reservation for multiple periods at one time. So the periods part in my database would look like this: period: one,two. When I make a new reservation just for period one it doesn't find the reservation i just made for period one and two and then double books period one. My question is what is the syntax to be able to loop through the periods and see if it has that one period even if there is multiple periods in the periods section?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// schema used to add a new reservation to the database
var ReservationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  dateScheduled: Date,
  category: String,
  item: String,
  user: String,
  period: String,
  roomNumber: String,
  numberOfStudents: Number,

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reservation', ReservationSchema);
```

This is my current call to my database. I am trying to find a a single word from my periods object in my database and if it finds it than and runs the else but if it doesn't it will create a new reservation. When I make a new reservation I can assign 2 periods at a time so its storing in my database as one,two but if I try to just find just period one it doesn't find anything. How can I make it loop through the periods and find anything with period one in it?

```
Reservation.find({'dateScheduled':dateIn, 'item':req.body.itemIn, 'period':{$in:[req.body.periodIn]}}, function( err, results){
    console.log('The Results', results);
    if( results.length === 0 ){
      newReservation.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(201);
        }//end else
      });//end save
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(400);
    } // end else
  });
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you question is not clear, please edit the question to make it more understandable

Comment: I have updated my question. Let me know if it is still confusing.

Comment: period is an array of strings or just a single string? Also, what does this mean : `So the periods part in my database would look like this: period: one,two`